# Dense Rank Show incorrect value

Tags: sql

I'm using below query

```
select dense_rank() over ( partition by BAF order by GRADE desc ) rnk,
       BAF, GRADE 
from TABLE
```

I'm getting below incorrect results values

```
rnk   BAF     GRADE
17     AB     2M-70
18     AB     2M-192
```

Could you please tell, why  2M-70 get rank 17 and 2M-192 rank 18.

Answer (score 0):

From the context it seems your GRADE is saved as a string type such as `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`. That means the `ORDER BY` will be done purely by text and will not interpret it as a number; Thus in descending order the character '7' comes before '1'.